# Files.copy() always falls 1 byte short of completion

Tags: java, io, copy

The file I'm downloading is 3,855,549 bytes and when I attempt to download it using the code below it always falls short by one byte to 3,855,548. I have absolutely no clue why this is happening, I've looked at the API to no avail. Nothing is thrown, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
        website = new URL(link);
        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "java_file.jar");
        try (InputStream IS = website.openStream()) {
            Files.copy(IS, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried fetching the file with curl or wget to see if you get similar results? Also take a look at [MCVE], it doesn't look like the code you've included is the code you're actually running.

Comment: This is all the code I am running for the download. I'll take a look at your link.

Comment: It's not because the code you've pasted has syntax errors. But again, do some basic verification of the download by other means.